# How to serialize property of class that has relationship with another class in python sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

When trying to make JSON endpoints for content in the database with sqlalchemy using *jsonify* in Flask where the contents Class has a function defined inside it to serialize based on the Class structure. everything works fine except where property of Class has a relationship with another Class.

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Owner(Base):
    __tablename__ = "owner"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(250), nullable=False)


class Store(Base):
    __tablename__ = "store"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('owner.id'))
    owner = relationship(Owner)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
                'id': self.id,
                'name': self.name,
                'owner_id': self.owner_id,
                'owner': self.owner
                }


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String)
    img_url = Column(String)
    price = Column(Integer)
    store_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('store.id'))
    store = relationship(Store)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('owner.id'))
    owner = relationship(Owner)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
                'id': self.id,
                'name': self.name,
                'description': self.description,
                'img_url': self.img_url,
                'price': self.price,
                'store_id': self.store_id,
                'store': self.store,
                'owner_id': self.owner_id,
                'owner': self.owner
                }
```

The syntax I'm using inside the flask app is:

```
@app.route('/market/stores/JSON')
def json_stores():
    """Return JSON of all the stores in the market."""
    stores = session.query(Store).all()
    return jsonify(stores=[i.serialize for i in stores])

@app.route('/catalog/store/<int:store_id>/JSON')
def json_item_in(store_id):
    """Return JSON of all the products in the store."""

    products = session.query(Item).filter_by(store_id=store_id).all()
    return jsonify(products=[i.serialize for i in products])
```

**For example, from Class, If I remove:**

```
'owner': self.owner
```

and:
    'store': self.store,

**The result return without any errors, page return JSON for the content in the same structure I defined in Class.**

I can't figure out the correct syntax for that, I tried to refer the class name directly:

```
'owner': Owner.name
```

didn't work.

I simply want the JSON page to display the owner name of the product using the same method (I'm aware there are other ways to return JSON for the content).

Comment: `{... 'store': self.store.name, 'owner': self.owner.name}`?

Comment: @SuperShoot Yes it worked! thanks a lot, please make it as answer so I can approve it.